# Apex chart Heatmap column Order change

Tags: vue.js, heatmap, apexcharts

I am new in the apex chart. I am implementing Heatmap using the apex chart in vuejs. So I am facing a problem with the update column of the heatmap. I am trying to reorder options > x-axis > categories array but it does not work for me. In this case Column title is updated but data is not reorder.
Can any buddy help me with it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option properties are not synchronized with each other changes. You just need to reorder the `data` array accordingly. This is my simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/kvipe/vax7udq9/4/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer here. Yes, I already did this with reordering data also. As I had tried to find something connected with the column so we don't have to manually reorder but I couldn't So used that reordering manually.